# How Should I Properly Return True/False From a Meteor Template Helper?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars, meteor-helper

its there a simple way to accomplish this.

```
Template.example.helpers({
 showElement : function(){
 var number = Session.get('number')
 if(number === 1){
     console.log(number)
    return true;
   } else {
    console.log(number)
    return false;
   }
  }
})
```

For example lets say i have this 2 events setting to 1 and to 0

```
//Setting to 1
Template.example.events({
'click #setToOne' : function(e,t){
   Session.set('number',1)
  }
})
 //Setting to 0
Template.example.events({
'click #setToZero' : function(e,t){
   Session.set('number',0)
  }
})
```

So this is actually working because the  `console.log` inside the helper are showing `0 and 1`

But how to call that `helper` on the `template`?

Already try this

```
<template name="example">
{{#if showElement.true}}
 <h1>show this header if Truee</h1>
{{else}}
<h1>show this header if False</h1>
{{/if}}
</template>
```

So what this is a best practice? or should i use `UI.registerHelper?`(i don't really know how to works with UI.registerHelpers)

Thanks for the help in advice

Answer (score 2):

```
<template name="example">
{{#if showElement}}
 <h1>show this header if Truee</h1>
{{else}}
<h1>show this header if False</h1>
{{/if}}
</template>
```

Comment: Btw in your helper you can simply return Session.get('number');, 0 is treated as false

Answer (score 2):

Let's take your problem and make a generic session variable equality checker helper:

```
Template.registerHelper('checkSession',function(sessionVarName,compareTo){
  return ( Session.get(sessionVarName) === compareTo );
});
```

With your specific variable name and comparison you could use this from any template with:

```
{{#if checkSession 'number' 1}}
```

which translates to *if the session variable labeled 'number' is === 1*

Comment: Thanks @Michel Floy for the answer, kinda old question haha my first steps with Meteor =p

Comment: I know! It just showed up in my list of related questions and I thought it deserved an up-to-date and more generally useful answer.